# Issue with Android view of a website: presence of a bar which is not displayed on a desktop browser

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have an issue about the phone view of a website that I have created. On classical desktop browsers (tested with Chrome, Firefox), I added for get responsive behavior :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Unfortunately, unlike the classical view, the view on Android browsers (Tested also with Chrome and Firefox android), I have an extra horizontal grey bar which appears on the top-right of page (above main menu "sciences-coding" and I don't know where this bar comes from ?

Here the [link][2] where you can see better the issue on your android and compare it to desktop browser : maybe someone will find the origin of this bar on Android (I don't know if this is also the case on iPhone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not related to Android or iOS. It happens in all devices since it’s a **layout** issue. I see this bar on my MacBook Pro using Firefox, for example:

[image]

However, it *seems* a scrollbar, but it isn’t. It’s generated by this HTML element:

```
<div class="horizontal_column">
```

to which these CSS rules are applied:

```
border-color: #000000;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 0 0 0;
```

As you can see by changing these rules, the “fake scrollbar” change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I don't understand, I have set this element to black color (into CSS : `border-color: #000000;`). So normally, it should not appear as grey, shoudn't it ? And more stange, on desktop browsers, I have not this grey bar, the entire thin bar is black. Are you sure from your side ? if yes, could you suggest a way to circumvent this issue ? Regards

Comment: jus a precision, please could you cut the image you put in your answer, just to remove all the text present below the main menu (containg an email address). I would really appreciate.

Comment: I changed the image. You need to resize the browser window to see it on the desktop. I don’t exactly understand the reason why the bar appears since I’d need to study the code better, but it’s surely caused by a bug in the layout rules. I suggest you remove the three CSS rules.

Comment: Thanks, I am going  to try your suggestion, keep you informed.

Comment: Solution surely found !, I have to add to `div.center_div` following CSS : `background-color: black;`